# Randomly arrange images in beamer

Tags: beamer, graphics

I would like to arrange images in a beamer presentation without having to set them in a predefined position.
Is there a package or a fast way to place randomly into the beamer a given number of images?

```
\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth]{img1}
    \includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth]{img2}
    \includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth]{img3}
\end{figure}
```

I would like to move them in the beamer and not having them on the same line.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) to demonstrate your set-up.

Comment: How move, during presentation or while preparing the document?

Comment: I updated my answer with a command allowing you to use any number of images.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use TikZ's nodes and `rnd` to randomize the position; the command `\PlaceImageRnd` has as mandatory argument a comma separated list of the image name files:

```
\PlaceImageRnd{<image-1>,<image-2>,...,<image-n>}
```

The line

```
\pgfmathsetseed{\pdfuniformdeviate 10000000}
```

makes each run of the code to update the locations.

The code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand\PlaceImageRnd[1]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \pgfmathsetseed{\pdfuniformdeviate 10000000}
  \pgfmathparse{2.0*rnd+1.0}
  \foreach \Image in {#1}
  {
    \node at (10*rnd,6*rnd) 
      {\includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth]{\Image}};
  }
  \end{tikzpicture}% 
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\PlaceImageRnd{example-image-a,example-image-b,example-image-c}
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

On the first run I got:

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to ensure the nodes don't overlap?